# Getting ordered list of class/modules implementing instance methods for method inheritance order/super

Tags: ruby

I'm including several modules in a Ruby class (in Ruby 2.0.0p247), some that define the same instance method and are all included in the same class. I'd like some code to generate a hash of each method name symbol to the list of classes in the inheritance hierarchy that implement that method, in order that they would be executed. How would I do that?

(That way I know when I call each `x` method, if each were to do `super if defined?(super)`, I know the order of method execution.)

E.g. given class C that implements instance method x, where C includes modules A and B that both implement instance method x, then I could use some code to inspect C to result in something like:

```
=> {:x=>[C, A, B], ...}
```

*To clarify, I want to know all of the methods that are inherited through modules and class inheritance, not just those that were defined on C.*

*Another example to show what I'm looking for:*

```
module A
  def v
  end
  def x
  end
end

module B
  def x
  end
  def y
  end
end

module D
  def a
  end
end

class E
  include A, B
  def x
  end
  def y
  end
  def z
  end
end

class C < E
  include D
end
```

*For that the result for C should be:*

```
 => {:a=>[D], :x=>[E, A, B], :y=>[E, B], :z=>[E], :v=>[A], :nil?=>[Kernel], :====>[Kernel], :=~=>[Kernel], :!~=>[Kernel], :eql?=>[Kernel], :hash=>[Kernel], :<=>=>[Kernel], :class=>[Kernel], :singleton_class=>[Kernel], :clone=>[Kernel], :dup=>[Kernel], :taint=>[Kernel], :tainted?=>[Kernel], :untaint=>[Kernel], :untrust=>[Kernel], :untrusted?=>[Kernel], :trust=>[Kernel], :freeze=>[Kernel], :frozen?=>[Kernel], :to_s=>[Kernel], :inspect=>[Kernel], :methods=>[Kernel], :singleton_methods=>[Kernel], :protected_methods=>[Kernel], :private_methods=>[Kernel], :public_methods=>[Kernel], :instance_variables=>[Kernel], :instance_variable_get=>[Kernel], :instance_variable_set=>[Kernel], :instance_variable_defined?=>[Kernel], :remove_instance_variable=>[Kernel], :instance_of?=>[Kernel], :kind_of?=>[Kernel], :is_a?=>[Kernel], :tap=>[Kernel], :send=>[Kernel], :public_send=>[Kernel], :respond_to?=>[Kernel], :extend=>[Kernel], :display=>[Kernel], :method=>[Kernel], :public_method=>[Kernel], :define_singleton_method=>[Kernel], :object_id=>[Kernel], :to_enum=>[Kernel], :enum_for=>[Kernel], :===>[BasicObject], :equal?=>[BasicObject], :!=>[BasicObject], :!==>[BasicObject], :instance_eval=>[BasicObject], :instance_exec=>[BasicObject], :__send__=>[BasicObject], :__id__=>[BasicObject]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Hash[
  C.instance_methods.map {|m|
    [m, C.ancestors.select {|a| a.instance_methods(false).include?(m)}]}]
# => { x: [C, A, B] }
```

Comment: Nice! I should have been clearer in the question that I wanted to be able to include all inherited methods, not just those defined in class C. But your solution: `Hash[C.instance_methods(false).map{|m|[m,C.ancestors.select {|a| a.instance_methods(false).include?(m)}]}]` works awesomely when all of the methods are defined in class C.

Comment: Just remove the first `false`.

Comment: Almost, but that adds C in the inheritance chain even if it didn't define a method itself. I'll put a better example in the question, so you can see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt was:

```
instance_method_inheritance_chain = {}

C.instance_methods(false).each do |m|
  (instance_method_inheritance_chain[m] ||= []) << C
end

C.ancestors.each do |a|
  a.instance_methods(false).each do |m|
    (instance_method_inheritance_chain[m] ||= []) << a unless instance_method_inheritance_chain[m] && instance_method_inheritance_chain[m].include?(a)
  end
end

instance_method_inheritance_chain
```

But, using Jörg's answer as a starting point to shorten my previous answer, I came up with:

```
result = Hash[C.instance_methods(false).map {|m| [m, [C]]}]
C.ancestors.each {|a| a.instance_methods(false).each {|m| (result[m] ||= []) << a } }
result
```

or as a method:

```
def method_inheritance(klass)
  result = Hash[klass.instance_methods(false).map {|m| [m, [klass]]}]
  klass.ancestors.each {|a| a.instance_methods(false).each {|m| (result[m] ||= []) << a } }
  result # and maybe .reject{|m| m == :method_inheritance} if needed
end

method_inheritance(C)
```